# unable to generate mysql schema using spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot

I am trying generate `mysql` schema via my `springboot` application using property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create` But getting error stating `Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'books'`

application.properties file:

```
# SERVER
server.port = 5555
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
#spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy = org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

#spring.security.user.name=user
#spring.security.user.password=123
application.security.jwt.secret-key=404E635266556A597H3272357538782F413F4497H72B4B6250645367566B5970
application.security.jwt.expiration=7200000
application.security.jwt.refresh-token.expiration=604800000


spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=Books
```

Main class

```
package com.books;


import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;


@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.books.token","com.books.user"})
public class SecurityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityApplication.class, args);
    }   
}
```

entity class user

```
package com.books.user;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
import com.books.token.Token;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.OneToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import jakarta.persistence.Temporal;
import jakarta.persistence.TemporalType;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "_user")
public class User implements UserDetails {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;
  @Column(name="firstName")
  private String firstname;
  @Column(name="lastName")
  private String lastname;
  @Column(name="userName",unique = true)
  private String email;
  @Column(name="password")
  private String password;
  @Column(name="role")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private Role role;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<Token> tokens;

  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
  @Column(name="createdDate")
  private Date createdDate;
  @Column(name="updatedDate")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
  private Date updatedDate;
  @Column(name="refreshToken")
  private String refreshToken;
  
  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return role.getAuthorities();
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return email;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

entity class token

```
package com.books.token;

import com.books.user.User;
import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.EnumType;
import jakarta.persistence.Enumerated;
import jakarta.persistence.FetchType;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToOne;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Token {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  public Integer id;

  @Column(unique = true)
  public String token;

  @Column(name = "tokenType")
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  public TokenType tokenType = TokenType.BEARER;

  
  public boolean revoked;

  public boolean expired;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  public User user;
}
```

No matter what I try `create` or `update` for `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` property, I am getting error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'books'
...
```

mysql dependency in POM.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

springboot version 3.0.5
and mysql db version is 8.0.32

Comment: Have you tried `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/books?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`?

Comment: No I haven't. Now trying...

Comment: YES! it DID worked finally! thanks a lot. I am wondering why is that magical flag needed, when there are already two properties set for the same reason `spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`.

Comment: I think, the other two properties relate to the database content, not the database itself. Glad it worked.

Comment: If your database is not created OR if your application can't connect to the DB. The ddl-flags provided will be ignored.

Comment: Ok. @Akhil noted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As told by @user1191247 I included `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true` with my

connection string and it worked. I did try many things. Change the driver

class `pom` `mysql` dependency, various versions.. nothing worked but at last on

@user1191247 advice I put the above flag, and it just clicked! Thank You so much.